# Preview window into userform

Tags: charts, export

I need a preview windows that contains data from cell A2.
Cell A2 is text.
I thought about exporting cell a2 as .bmp and opening it in the userform as an image, but when I use chart, I have a blank file. Does anyone have any ideas ?

[image]